# A Quotient of the Euclidean Group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

$\newcommand{\euc}{\mathscr I}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$
Let $\euc(n)$ denote the the Euclidean group $\R^n\rtimes O_n(\R)$.

Recall that $\euc(n)$ acts on $\R^n$ as $(\mathbf x, T)\cdot \mathbf y=\mathbf x+T\mathbf y$ for all $(\mathbf x, T)\in \euc(n)$ and $\mathbf y\in \R^n$.

Consider the action of $\euc(n)$ on $(\R^n)^v$ defined as follows:
$$
A\cdot(\mathbf y_1, \ldots, \mathbf y_v)=(A\cdot\mathbf y_1,\ldots, A\cdot\mathbf y_v)
$$
for all $A\in \euc(n)$ and $(\mathbf y_1,\ldots, \mathbf y_v)\in (\R^n)^v$.

Fix a point $\mathbf p=(\mathbf p_1, \ldots, \mathbf p_v)\in (\R^n)^v$ and define a map $F:\euc(n)\to (\R^n)^v$ as
$$
F(A)=(A\cdot\mathbf p_1,\ldots,A\cdot\mathbf p_v)
$$
for all $A\in \euc(n)$.

Since $F^{-1}(\mathbf p)$ is an isotropy subgroup of a Lie group action, we know that $F^{-1}(\mathbf p)$ is a Lie subgroup of $\euc(n)$. Now for some reason unknown to me, we can give a manifold structure to $\euc(n)/F^{-1}(\mathbf p)$ such that the natural projection map $\pi:\euc(n)\to \euc(n)/F^{-1}(\mathbf p)$ is a smooth submersion.

For set theoretical reasons, we can get a map $\bar F:\euc(n)/F^{-1}(\mathbf p)\to (\R^{n})^v$ such that $F=\bar F\circ \pi$.
Since $\pi$ is a smooth submersion, we infer that $\bar F$ is a smooth map.

---

**My Question:** Now on pg. 283 of [this](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/courses/2010_2/papers/TheRigidityOfGraphs.pdf) paper (titled '*The Rigidity of Graphs*' and written by *B. Roth* and *L. Asimow*), it is said that the map $\bar F:\euc(n)/F^{-1}(\mathbf p)\to \text{im}(\bar F)$ is a diffeomorphism.

It is not clear to me why is this map a diffeomorphism. In fact, it is not even clear why is $\text{im}(\bar F)$ a smooth manifold.

Comment: Please refer to the paper not only by a link but with author and title. If the URL stops working, for example, your question becomes incomplete, and we do not want that.

Comment: Regarding the differentiable structure on a quotient $G/H$, where $G$ is a Lie group, and $H$ is a closed Lie subgroup, this is "standard material". Any book which talks about homogeneous spaces will contain that (for example, Helgason's book "Differential Geometry, Lie Groups and Symmetric Spaces" comes to mind). What you are asking about is just a particular case of a homogeneous space, which can be thought of either as $G/H$, or as an orbit of $G$ with stabilizer $H$.